# Not working to upgrade a custom module CMS page

Tags: magento2

I followed [this guide](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-create-cms-pages-programmatically.html) to register my custom module as a CMS page using the UpgradeDataInterface

For some reason, the version it uploaded was an older one (cached or something maybe?) so I tried deleting it from the content > pages menu. Now, I can't seem to be able to register it again. I have tried using UpgradeData and changing the version on my Module.xml (as per the guide above), and also used the InstallDataInterface via [this guide](http://www.herveguetin.com/create-cms-blocks-and-pages-programmatically/).

I am using the `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` function and not seeing any results. Could this be a cacheing issue? Any idea on what steps to try to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way, if you want to upgrade you module again, just delete the record of your module in `setup_module` table in database and run:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: would that be the modules record in the `mg_setup_module` database?

Comment: That is the record in your magento database

Comment: When run setup:upgrade command, Magento will check all the version of module in your code, with the version in setup_module table. IF not or greater, this module will update.

Comment: as you see, the function `$context->getVersion()` will take the version in `setup_module` table.

Answer (score 1):

Found a post from Marius answering the question.

I wasn't changing the version in the actual UpgradeData file.. which I guess you need to do. I had changed the module version:

```
<module name="Company_Module" setup_version="1.2.0">
```

but had not changed the version in the UpgradeData class. Since I wanted to upgrade to my new "1.2" version, I needed to write:

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.2.0') < 0) {
```